# Ruby on Rails: pass query parameters hash with key but nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Ruby on Rails, my current url has a query parameter of `?hello`. Since the `request.query_parameters` hash will be `{:hello=>nil}`, how do I pass this with `link_to`? Rails seems to drop any query parameter that has a nil value.

Comment: @Eyeslandic I am asking how to pass a query parameter with a nil value to `link_to`. If I do `link_to(some_path, :hello=>nil)` I would like to see `?hello` in the url. As it is, Rails will drop any query parameter that has a nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's really an elegant way. The best hack seems to be something like this:

```
_hello = '?hello' if request.query_parameters.fetch(:hello, false).nil?
link_to('click here', some_path+"#{_hello}")
```